Snackbar Error: Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps
I am trying to implement a showSnackBar on my App but I am getting this error:
Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.
Try rewriting the code to not use the 'BuildContext', or guard the use with a 'mounted' check.
Here is my code:
//Post reply
replyThread() async{
  setState(() { _isSubmitted = true; });
  try{
      var res = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(API.quickThreadReplyURL),
        body: {
            'post_id': _postid.toString(),
            'userID': userID.toString(),
            'sessionData': sessionData.toString(),
            'content': contentController.text,
        },
      );
      if(res.statusCode==200){
          //Clear textfield
          contentController.text = '';
          final resBody = jsonDecode(res.body);
          bool success = resBody['success'];
          if(success){
              List thread = resBody['threadList'] as List;
              setState(() {
                threadReplies = thread + threadReplies;
                _isSubmitted = false;
              });
              //Show toaster
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 247, 92),
                  content: 
                  Text(
                    "New thread reply successfully posted",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                )
              );
          }
          else{
            setState(() { _isSubmitted = false; });
            //Show toaster
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 96, 96),
                content: 
                Text(
                  "Oops! Something went wrong. Reply not posted",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)),
                ),
              )
            );
        }
      }
  }
  catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
  }
}


It is just a warning, but you should fix it. Because after async gaps, BuildContext maybe unmounted:
if (mounted) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(...);
}


Should I use if (context.mounted) {} or just if (mounted) {} ?

That depends on what Flutter version you are using, context.mounted only supported after Flutter 3.17

You could check async logic like below:
var res = await http.post(...);
if (!context.mounted) return;
if (res.statusCode == 200) {
...

Refer the following link:
https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/use_build_context_synchronously

I would like to suggest instead of passing BuildContext context in a snckbar, use the below solution which may be fix your issue of async gaps
1.Create one snackbar_utils.dart file and add this in your existing project.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SnackbarUtil {
  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  static void showSnackbar(String message, {Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 2), Color backgroundColor = Colors.black}) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(message,style:TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 12)),
      duration: duration,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    );

    scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  static void showErrorSnackbar(String message, {Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 2)}) {
    showSnackbar(message, duration: duration, backgroundColor: Colors.red);
  }

  static void showSuccessSnackbar(String message, {Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 2)}) {
    showSnackbar(message, duration: duration, backgroundColor: Color(0xff96DBF8));
  }
} 

// Add this line into your MaterialApp
MaterialApp(
  scaffoldMessengerKey: SnackbarUtil.scaffoldMessengerKey,
  ///your existing code
)

//usage :
 if(res.statusCode==200){
//Clear textfield
contentController.text = '';
final resBody = jsonDecode(res.body);
bool success = resBody['success'];
if(success){
///...existing code
//Show Snackbar
SnackbarUtil.showSnackbar("New thread reply successfully posted",backgroundColor:Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 247, 92) );            
          }}


When you say my existing code, do you mean something like this?
MaterialApp(
scaffoldMessengerKey: SnackbarUtil.scaffoldMessengerKey,
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 247, 92),
              content: 
              Text(
                "New thread reply successfully posted",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            )
          );

),

How do I call this on my UI to display the snackbar?

No, you can use like
if(res.statusCode==200){
//Clear textfield
contentController.text = '';
final resBody = jsonDecode(res.body);
bool success = resBody['success'];
if(success){
///your existing code
//Show Snackbar
SnackbarUtil.showSnackbar("New thread reply successfully posted",backgroundColor:Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 247, 92) );
}}

Whoa... this simplifies the entire process and makes it re-usable across my app. Thanks

That's fantastic! Re-usability is a great benefit for any app.

If you get an error like Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps....

... AND the error is on the line of popping (or pushing), like Navigator.pop(context); NOT following anything else => use if (!mounted) return; before popping.

... AND the error is on the line of popping (or pushing), like Navigator.pop(context); following something more => use if (mounted) { Navigator.pop(context); }.

... AND the error is on the line of showSnackBar or anyhting else using context => use if (mounted) { ...context...; }.


If you get an error like Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps, guarded by an unrelated 'mounted' check....

... REPLACE mounted in the previous examples with context.mounted, like if (context.mounted) { ...context...; }.

If you should have something weird like I have:
await showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  context: navigatorKey.currentState!.context,
  builder: ...
);

then this works:
BuildContext c = navigatorKey.currentState!.context;
if (c.mounted) {
  await showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: c,
    builder: ...
  );
}

